# TurnManager logic in Unity executes both if and else conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, multiplayer

In my unity project the turnManager executes an erroneous loop when the player makes a correct 'guess'. I struggle to identify the problem and would be grateful for any return.
To the best of my understanding, it seems to be a game logic issue.

Game logic wise, the turn manager was designed to check a condition (if a given player has a given card). De facto, after executing the if section of the loop (the correct/true condition), it executes automatically the else part as well (the condition is false). This ends player's turn... rather than providing the currentPlayer (the player with the turn) another try to 'guess a card'.

I suspect it's a problem with the turnmanger code, rather than Unity's settings etc'. My assumption is based that I could refute other, i.e. the following, issues:

1. Multiple clicks - that is because the click which triggers the guess/condition verification works as expected when the 'guess' is wrong, when the 'guess' is wrong as executed as expected.
2. Other calls for the false methods from other scripts: The methods that are called by the false/wrong 'guess' verification are called by, or appear at, turnmanager only. No other class or script calls these methods( DrawCardFromDeck and EndTurn).
3. A wrong methodical call: In other words, The problem is the same either if the method that calls the guess verification is ( OnEventGuessClick ), is based on triggering an Event m or a direct dependency call.
4. Following the debug.logs it appears that the Else snippet is execute after the PlayerController is updated, which it should be, i.e. to represents the current player's hand, quartets and cards to guess. It may be that some element in the UI update triggers another OnEventGuessClick. Yet, it's a guess as I cannot substantiate it.

The main issue, I suppose is that the code seems correct, while it isn't. I.e. I cannot find which problem I should fix.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Below are the scripts. I excluded only the parts which I could definitely exclude, which makes it a bit long. And a couple of notes for the scripts attached below:

a. Besides the above mentioned issue, the project runs as expected in play mode.

b. TurnManager is called via GameFlowManager.StartTurnManager, not when the game starts.

c. To separate the game logic and UI logic the player.cs is the only project which passes data to PlayerController.

```html
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Linq;
     
    public class Player : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // Existing attributes
        public int ID;
        public string playerName; // Renamed 'name' to 'playerName' to avoid conflict
        public int score;
        public int result = 0;
        public bool isWinner;
        private bool _hasTurn;
     
        public bool hasTurn
        {
            get { return _hasTurn; }
            set
            {
                _hasTurn = value; // Simply set the value
                Debug.Log($"{playerName}: from player script hasTurn is set to {hasTurn}");
                // Notify listeners about attribute changes
                OnPlayerAttributesChanged?.Invoke(this);
            }
        }
     
        // Properties for the player's cards, hand, quartets, and score text
        public List<Card> HandCards { get; set; }
        public List<Card> CardsPlayerCanAsk { get; private set; }
        public Transform PlayerHand { get; set; }
        public Transform PlayerQuartets { get; set; }
        public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI ScoreText { get; set; }
        public TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI ResultText { get; set; }
        // Property to display other players' names excluding the current player
        public List<Player> PlayerToAsk { get; private set; } = new List<Player>();
        private List<Card> _previousCards; // Store the previous state of Cards
     
        private CardManager cardManager;
        // Event to notify listeners when player attributes change
        public event System.Action<Player> OnPlayerAttributesChanged;
     
        private void Awake()
        {
            GameObject managersGameObject = GameObject.Find("Managers");
     
            if (managersGameObject != null)
            {
                // Get the CardManager component from the Managers GameObject
                cardManager = managersGameObject.GetComponent<CardManager>();
     
                if (cardManager == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("CardManager component not found on the Managers GameObject.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Managers GameObject not found in the scene.");
            }
     
                HandCards = new List<Card>();
                CardsPlayerCanAsk = new List<Card>();
        }
     
        // Constructor to initialize the player with the initial turn status
        public Player(bool initialTurn)
        {
            _hasTurn = initialTurn;
            OnPlayerAttributesChanged?.Invoke(this);
        }
     
        public void SetPlayerToAsk(List<Player> playersToAsk)
        {
            PlayerToAsk = playersToAsk;
        }
     
        // Player.cs
        public void AddCardToHand(Card card)
        {
            HandCards.Add(card);
     
            // Set the card's parent to the player's hand
            card.gameObject.transform.SetParent(PlayerHand);
     
            Debug.Log($"Card added to Hand. Total cards in HandCards: {HandCards.Count}");
            CheckForQuartets();
            UpdateCardsPlayerCanAsk();
            // Notify listeners about attribute changes
            OnPlayerAttributesChanged?.Invoke(this);
        }
     
        public void RemoveCardFromHand(Card card)
        {
            HandCards.Remove(card);
            Debug.Log($"Card added to Hand. Total cards in HandCards: {HandCards.Count}");
            CheckForQuartets();
            UpdateCardsPlayerCanAsk();
            // Notify listeners about attribute changes
            OnPlayerAttributesChanged?.Invoke(this);
        }
     
        public void UpdateCardsPlayerCanAsk()
        {
            CardsPlayerCanAsk.Clear();
            foreach (Card card in cardManager.AllCards)
            {
                if (HandCards.Any(playerCard => playerCard.rank == card.rank) && !HandCards.Contains(card))
                {
                    CardsPlayerCanAsk.Add(card);
                }
            }
     
            OnPlayerAttributesChanged?.Invoke(this);
        }
     
        public void CheckForQuartets()
        {
            var groupedCards = HandCards.GroupBy(card => card.rank);
     
            foreach (var group in groupedCards)
            {
                if (group.Count() >= 4)
                {
                    MoveCardsToQuartetsArea(group.ToList());
                }
            }
        }
     
        public void MoveCardsToQuartetsArea(List<Card> quartetCards)
        {
            //...
        }
     
        // Check if the player's hand is empty
        public bool IsHandEmpty()
        {
            return HandCards.Count == 0;
        }
    }
     
     
    using UnityEngine;
    using TMPro;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
     
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public TMP_Text playerNameText;
        public TMP_Text playerScoreText;
        public TMP_Text playerTurnText;
        public Transform PlayerHand;
        public Transform PlayerQuartetsArea;
     
        public TMP_Dropdown cardsDropdown; // Dropdown for cards player can ask
        public TMP_Dropdown playersDropdown; // Dropdown for active players
        public Button guessButton; // Button for guess request
     
        public delegate void GuessButtonClickHandler(Card selectedCard, Player selectedPlayer);
        public static event GuessButtonClickHandler OnGuessButtonClick;
     
        private List<Card> CardsPlayerCanAsk;
        private List<Player> PlayerToAsk;
        private List<Card> InitialCards; // Placeholder for cards dropdow
     
        private List<int> playerIDs = new List<int>();
        private List<int> cardIDs = new List<int>();
     
        private CardManager cardManager;
     
        public Player AssociatedPlayer { get; set; } // Add this field
       
     
        public void SetPlayerData(Player player)
        {
            AssociatedPlayer = player;
     
            player.OnPlayerAttributesChanged += OnPlayerAttributesChanged;
     
            CardsPlayerCanAsk = player.CardsPlayerCanAsk;
            PlayerToAsk = player.PlayerToAsk;
     
            playerNameText.text = player.playerName; // Use playerName instead of name
            playerScoreText.text = "Score: " + player.score;
     
            playerTurnText.text = player.hasTurn ? "Turn: Yes" : "Turn: No";
     
            // Populate the playersDropdown with active players (excluding the current player)
            UpdatePlayersDropdown(AssociatedPlayer.PlayerToAsk); // Pass the list of player names
     
            // Update the cardsDropdown with cards that the player can ask
            UpdateCardsDropdown(AssociatedPlayer.CardsPlayerCanAsk);
     
            // Deactivate the turn UI objects for players without turn
            if (!player.hasTurn)
            {
                cardsDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                playersDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                guessButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                cardsDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                playersDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                guessButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
     
        private void OnPlayerAttributesChanged(Player player)
        {
            // Update the score text when the attributes change
            playerNameText.text = player.playerName;
            playerScoreText.text = "Score: " + player.score;
     
            playerTurnText.text = player.hasTurn ? "Turn: Yes" : "Turn: No";
            Debug.Log("OnPlayerAttributesChanged is called");
     
            foreach (Card card in player.HandCards)
            {
                card.gameObject.transform.SetParent(PlayerHand);
            }
     
            UpdatePlayersDropdown(player.PlayerToAsk);
            UpdateCardsDropdown(player.CardsPlayerCanAsk);
     
            // Update the UI activation
            ActivatePlayerTurnUI(player.hasTurn);
            if (player.hasTurn)
            {
                // Activate the turn UI objects for the player with the current turn
                cardsDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                playersDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                guessButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                // Deactivate the turn UI objects for the player whose turn has ended
                cardsDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                playersDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                guessButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
     
        }
     
        public void UpdatePlayersDropdown(List<Player> updatedPlayersToAsk)
        {
            Debug.Log("UpdatePlayersDropdown is called");
            if (updatedPlayersToAsk != null && updatedPlayersToAsk.Count > 0)
            {
                // Clear the current dropdown options and lists
                playersDropdown.ClearOptions();
                playerIDs.Clear();
     
                // Add the player names to the dropdown and store their IDs
                List<string> playerNames = updatedPlayersToAsk.Select(player =>
                {
                    playerIDs.Add(player.ID);
                    return player.playerName;
                }).ToList();
     
                playersDropdown.AddOptions(playerNames);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Updated players list is null or empty.");
            }
        }
     
        public void UpdateCardsDropdown(List<Card> cards)
        {
            if (cardsDropdown != null)
            {
                cardsDropdown.ClearOptions();
                cardIDs.Clear();
     
                if (cards != null)
                {
                    List<string> cardNames = new List<string>();
     
                    foreach (Card card in cards)
                    {
                        cardIDs.Add(card.ID);
                        cardNames.Add(formattedCardEntry);    
                    }
     
                    cardsDropdown.AddOptions(cardNames);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("UpdateCardsDropdown - cards is null");
                }
            }
        }
     
     
        public void HandleGuessButtonClick()
        {
            // Disable the button to prevent multiple clicks
            guessButton.interactable = false;
     
            Debug.Log("HandleGuessButtonClick called");
     
            // Get the selected index from the dropdowns
            int selectedPlayerIndex = playersDropdown.value;
            int selectedCardIndex = cardsDropdown.value;
     
            // Use the selected index to access the corresponding IDs
            int selectedPlayerID = playerIDs[selectedPlayerIndex];
            int selectedCardID = cardIDs[selectedCardIndex];
     
            // Find the corresponding Card and Player objects based on IDs
            Card selectedCard = CardsPlayerCanAsk.Find(card => card.ID == selectedCardID);
            Player selectedPlayer = PlayerToAsk.Find(player => player.ID == selectedPlayerID);
     
            Debug.Log($"Selected Card ID: {selectedCardID}, Selected Player ID: {selectedPlayerID}");
            Debug.Log($"Selected Card: {selectedCard.cardName}");
            Debug.Log($"Selected Player: {selectedPlayer.playerName}");
     
            // Directly call the HandlePlayerTurn method in TurnManager
            TurnManager turnManager = GameObject.Find("Managers").GetComponent<TurnManager>();
            if (turnManager != null)
            {
                turnManager.OnGuessButtonClick(selectedCard, selectedPlayer);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("TurnManager not found.");
            }
     
            // Re-enable the button after the method is called
            guessButton.interactable = true;
     
            Debug.Log("HandleGuessButtonClick finished");
        }
     
        public void ActivatePlayerTurnUI(bool isActive)
        {
            cardsDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(isActive);
            playersDropdown.gameObject.SetActive(isActive);
            guessButton.gameObject.SetActive(isActive);
        }
     
    }
     
     
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
     
    public class TurnManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public PlayerManager playerManager;
        public CardManager cardManager;
        private List<Card> deckCards;
        private bool isInitialized = false;
        private Card selectedCard;
        private Player selectedPlayer;
        private Player currentPlayer;
        private bool isPlayerUIEnabled = true;
        private bool isDrawingCard = false;
     
        private bool hasHandledCurrentPlayer = false;
     
        private void Awake()
        {
            PlayerController.OnGuessButtonClick += OnGuessButtonClick;
        }
     
        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            PlayerController.OnGuessButtonClick -= OnGuessButtonClick;
        }
     
        private void Start()
        {
            StartTurnManager();
        }
     
        public void StartTurnManager()
        {
            if (!isInitialized)
            {
                if (cardManager != null)
                {
                    deckCards = cardManager.GetDeckCards();
                    Debug.Log($"Total number of cards in turn manager deckCards are: {deckCards.Count}");
                    isInitialized = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError($"{Time.time}: CardManager reference is not assigned.");
                }
     
                currentPlayer = playerManager.Players.Find(player => player.hasTurn);
     
                if (currentPlayer != null)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(TurnLoop());
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogError("No initial player with hasTurn == true found.");
                }
            }
        }
     
        public void OnGuessButtonClick(Card selectedCard, Player selectedPlayer)
        {
            Debug.Log($"OnGuessButtonClick - Selected Card: {selectedCard}, Selected Player: {selectedPlayer}");
            this.selectedCard = selectedCard;
            this.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayer;
     
            if (currentPlayer != null && !isDrawingCard)
            {
                HandlePlayerTurn(currentPlayer); // Moved to HandlePlayerTurn
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"{Time.time}: Invalid player turn.");
            }
        }
     
        private System.Collections.IEnumerator TurnLoop()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (currentPlayer.hasTurn)
                {
                    if (!hasHandledCurrentPlayer)
                    {
                        HandlePlayerTurn(currentPlayer);
                        hasHandledCurrentPlayer = true;
                    }
                }
     
                if (!currentPlayer.hasTurn)
                {
                    hasHandledCurrentPlayer = false;
                    NextCurrentPlayer();
                }
     
                yield return null;
            }
        }
     
        private void HandlePlayerTurn(Player currentPlayer)
        {
            if (selectedCard == null && selectedPlayer == null)
            {
                MakeGuess();
            }
            else
            {
                AskForCard(selectedCard, selectedPlayer);
            }
        }
     
        private void MakeGuess()
        {
            //this method will Enable, disable the turn UI, currently not developed.
            Debug.Log("MakeGuess method is called");
        }
     
        private void AskForCard(Card selectedCard, Player selectedPlayer)
        {
            if (selectedPlayer != null && selectedCard != null)
            {
                if (selectedPlayer.HandCards.Contains(selectedCard))
                {
                    Debug.Log("AskForCar guess is correct");
                    TransferCard(selectedCard, currentPlayer);
                    CheckForQuartets();
     
                    // If the guess is correct and the player's hand isn't empty, allow another guess.
                    if (!IsPlayerHandEmpty(currentPlayer))
                    {
                        // Allow the player to make another guess without drawing a card or ending the turn.
                        HandlePlayerTurn(currentPlayer);
                    }
                    else if (deckCards.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // If the player's hand is empty but the deck isn't, draw a card from the deck.
                        DrawCardFromDeck();
                        // After drawing a card, re-evaluate the hand.
                        if (!IsPlayerHandEmpty(currentPlayer))
                        {
                            // Allow the player to make another guess.
                            // Remove the EndTurn() call from here.
                            HandlePlayerTurn(currentPlayer);
                        }
                    }
                    // No need to check for the deck being empty here, as we've already handled that case.
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the guess is wrong, draw a card from the deck and end the turn.
                    DisplayMessage($"{selectedPlayer.playerName} does not have {selectedCard.cardName}.");
                    DrawCardFromDeck();
                    EndTurn(); // This is the correct place to call EndTurn for an incorrect guess.
                }
            }
        }
     
     
        private void TransferCard(Card selectedCard, Player curPlayer)
        {
            selectedPlayer.RemoveCardFromHand(selectedCard);
            currentPlayer.AddCardToHand(selectedCard);
        }
     
        private bool IsPlayerHandEmpty(Player currentPlayer)
        {
            return currentPlayer.IsHandEmpty();
        }
     
        private void EndTurn()
        {
            NextCurrentPlayer();
        }
     
        private void NextCurrentPlayer()
        {
            int currentIndex = playerManager.Players.IndexOf(currentPlayer);
            int nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % playerManager.Players.Count;
            currentPlayer.hasTurn = false;
            Player nextPlayer = playerManager.Players[nextIndex];
            nextPlayer.hasTurn = true;
            currentPlayer = nextPlayer;
        }
     
        private void CheckForQuartets()
        {
            currentPlayer.CheckForQuartets(); // Implement your quartet-checking logic here
        }
     
        private void DisplayMessage(string message)
        {
     
            Debug.Log("Display Message: " + message);
        }
     
        public void DrawCardFromDeck()
        {
            if (cardManager != null && currentPlayer != null)
            {
                cardManager.DrawCardFromDeck(currentPlayer);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"{Time.time}: CardManager reference or current player or selected card is not assigned.");
            }
        }
     
        private void CheckGameEnd()
        {
            //...
        }
     
        private void GameEnd()
        {
            Debug.Log($"{Time.time}: Game Ended");
        }
    }
```

Comment: no chance you have more than one instance?

Comment: Perhaps someone will help you if you share the project in some way, since parts of the code can take a long time to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try renaming the function that is mapped on the button's onclick in the UI, so that you definitively break any button or UI calling that method. After that, add your own OnClick handler directly by adding a Button field and dragging the button into it:

```
[SerializeField] Button buttonToBeClicked;

void Awake(){ 
buttonToBeClicked.onClick.AddListener( () => { OnEventGuessClickRenamed(); });
}
```

renaming the function will make sure nothing else is calling it by accident and rule out UI problems. adding the OnClick handler in awake via code then makes sure it's the only place you add it.
If something still seems wrong, step through in the debugger as well as adding more log output.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your idea. However, the problem remains. It seems that the execution of the If statement, triggers somehow, another execution. Though the secondary execution isn't an active onClick by the player but an arbitrary execution of another guess. I assume that since a wrong guess is more probable the correct one, the else segment is called. To ensure I properly implemented your idea, please note that I in playercontroller I added the above declaration, the Awake method and then renamed the onClick to OnEventGuessClickRenamed. No other changes were applied.